# How do I retrieve the value of a content changing p tag in every 5 sec?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How do I retrieve the contents of a content changing p tag in every 5 sec?
My code snippet as following.

```js
var word;
setInterval(function(){
    $.get("http://localhost/chrome-notification/dosya.php", function (data) {
       callback(data);
    });
},3000);

function callback(data){
    word=data;
    $('container').html(word);
}
```

```html
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>

    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>

</head>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="background.js"></script>
<body>
<p id="container">deneme</p>

</body>
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
```

retrieve value of p tag the second js file. 'console.log(text)' returning value is 'deneme'. To wit not changed value of p tag

**myscript.js**

```js
var text= $('#container').text();
console.log(text);

var opt={
    type: "basic",
    title: "Primary Title",
    message: text,
    iconUrl: "icon.png"
};
setInterval(function(){
    chrome.notifications.create("",opt,function(){});
},10000);
```

Comment: what are you trying to say here (To wit not changed value of p tag) ??

Comment: your second script tag is out of body, try putting it before </body> and re run code

Answer (score 0):

Your second `script tag`  is out of body, try putting it before `</body>` and also change

```
$('container').html(word);
```

to

```
$('#container').html(word);
```

hope this works :)

Comment: not working maaan, stil returned 'deneme' . the value of p tag not changed.

Comment: looks like your "url" or php file has the problem. Because i have tried your code on my pc as well as on jsfiddle, it is working fine.  can u provide the file u want to load !?

Comment: Thanks vivek. I solved the problem.Problem,the text variable is undefined.Because "message:text" section of program running before the ajax request